# How to loop through a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to loop through a Pandas dataframe.  The list `L` includes values that are used to specify what row `X` or `Y` should begin from i.e., (1:, 2:, 3:).

```
list = [1,2,3]

for L in list:
    X = data.ix[L:, 'X':]
    Y = data.ix[L:, 'Y']     
    regressor = LinearRegression()
    regressor.fit(X, Y)
    prediction = regressor.predict([[Variable]])
```

The error when attempting the above is:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Comment: don't you mean `for l in L:`? You're trying to iterate over the `list` type, also why are you recreating the regression model on each iteration? just define it outside once and refer to it

Comment: Also all you're doing is just slicing the df incrementally, you can achieve the same by doing `for df in data.iloc[::1]: X = df['X'] Y = df['Y'] e.t.c.`

Comment: Ed, I am recreating the regression model on each iteration because each subset of X/Y is a different model with different results.  I'm essentially trying to do a regression with a rolling window of model inputs.

Comment: Ed, could you please lay out how exactly you would implement your solution.  I don't quite follow.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can do something like the following:

```
l = [1,2,3]
results = []

for idx in l:
    X = data.ix[idx:, 'X':]
    Y = data.ix[idx:, 'Y']     
    regressor = LinearRegression()
    regressor.fit(X, Y)
    results.append(regressor.predict([[Variable]]))
```

However, I don't know what `Variable` is here, you could also just do the following:

```
for df in data.iloc[::1]:
    regressor = LinearRegression()
    regressor.fit(df['X'], df['Y'])
    results.append(regressor.predict([[Variable]]))
```

Comment: Hi EdChum - The first example you posted is similar to the solution I gave.  I get the error: ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (4,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0).  For your second example, it is unclear to me how you are looping through the list of 1,2,3.

Comment: In the second example I don't loop through the list, it just shows how to iteratively slice the df, for your new error it supposed to be `X = data.ix[idx:, 'X']` instead?

Comment: I am getting the same error with:     for idx in list:X = data.ix[idx:, 'X':]
    Y = data.ix[idx:, 'Y']

Answer (score 0):

You should try iterrrows,[http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/basics.html#iterrows]

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1.5]], columns=['int', 'float'])
>>> row = next(df.iterrows())[1]
>>> row
int      1.0
float    1.5
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert it to dict or list in before and than use as you know:

```
list_from_df = df.to_list()
for item in list_from_df:
   print(item)
```

Or as a dict:

```
df.to_dict()
for key, value in list_from_df.items():
   print(key) # index
   print(value)
```