# How to replace string separator(,) in Numerical Columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, replace

I'm trying to covert "Quantity" column to int.

The quantity column has a string(,) divider or separator for the numerical values

using code

```
data['Quantity'] = data['Quantity'].astype('int')
```

```
data['Quantity'] = data['Quantity'].astype('float')
```

I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '16,000'

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '16,000'
```

### Data

```
Date         Quantity

2019-06-25       200
2019-03-30       100
2019-11-02       250
2018-10-23       100
2018-07-17       150
2018-05-31       150
2018-07-05       100
2018-10-04       100
2018-02-23       100
2019-09-16       204
2019-09-16       315
2019-11-09       113
2019-08-29         5
2019-08-23         4
2019-06-18        78
2019-12-06         4
2019-12-06         2
2019-10-03    16,000
2019-07-03     8,000
2018-12-12        32

Name: Quantity, dtype: object
```

It's a pandas dataframe with 124964 rows. I added the head and tail of the data

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Is this a pandas dataframe? Also, shouldn't there be `16,000` somewhere in your data?

Comment: Sorry for closing it immediately, I have too much reputation. I wonder if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-thousands-separato would solve your problem, but it doesn't involve a Pandas dataframe. But the use of `locale` is probably key. Because in the Netherlands 16,000 would mean 16, but in the US it means 16000.

Comment: It's a pandas dataframe with 124964 rows. I added the head  and tail of the data

Comment: What are you creating the dataframe from?  csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution

```
# Replace string "," with ""

data["Quantity"] = data["Quantity"].apply(lambda x: str(x.replace(',','')))

data['Quantity'] = data['Quantity'].astype('float')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
number = '16,000'
act_num = ''
for char in number:
    try:
        character = int(char)
        act_num+=(char)
    except:
        if char == '-' or char == '.':
            act_num+= (char)
print(float(act_num))
```

Comment: But that treats 16,000, -16000, 16.000 all as the same

Comment: @RemcoGerlich  I have edited the answer. Tried with all your examples and it works

Comment: @Krishna does it work? I haven't included the part where you loop through the dataframe but I trust you can do that

Comment: @Sid I'm unable to loop through the entire dataframe. Maybe I don't know how to do it. Please go through the updated question and let me know how to fix it

Comment: @Krishna sorry but I don't know how to work in pandas

Comment: But maybe this will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878573/how-to-loop-through-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

`'16,000'` is neither a valid representation of an int or float, and actually the format is ambiguous - depending on locale standard, it could mean either `16.0` (float) or `16000` (int).

You first need to specify how this data should be interpreted, then fix the string so that it's a valid representation of either a float or int, then apply `asType()` with the correct type.

To make `'16,000'` a valid float representation, you just have to replace the comma with a dot:

```
val = '16,000'
val = val.replace(",", ".")
```

To make it an int (with value `16000`) you just remove the comma:

```
val = '16,000'
val = val.replace(",", "")
```

I don't use panda so I can't tell how to best do this with a dataframe, but this is surely documented.

As a general rule: when working on data coming from the wild outside world (anything outside your own code), never trust the data, always make sure you validate and sanitize it before use.

Comment: It should be interpreted as 16000

Comment: Somehow I did it. Thank you for the Idea @bruno

Answer (score -2):

data.Quantity = data.Quantity.astype(str).astype(int)

Comment: There are decimal points as well, you will have to use ```float``` not ```int```

Comment: So use float instead int

Comment: @ShashwatHirapure welcome to SO and thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately, your answer is wrong (the data is already a string and this string cannot be turned into an integer), and doesn't match SO standards for a good answer (a good answer should not only provide a working solution, but also explain the solution).